# refresh a DIV without refresah a full page with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh, page-refresh, partial-page-refresh

I try to resfresh a div without refresh a full page.
the code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ext").on('click',function(event) {
    var url = $(this).prop('href');
    $("#change").load(url);
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="page1.html" class="ext">page 1</a>
<a href="page2.php" class="ext">page 2</a>

<div id="change">
  <a href="page3.html" class="ext">page 3</a>
  <a href="page4.php" class="ext">page 4</a>
</div>
```

for resfresh page1 and page2 no problem.
But when I want to resfresh page3 and page 4 all page is resfreshing.
I don't find the solution.
Can' you help me?

ps : sorry, I'am french and my language is bad.

Comment: The problem is because the content of the `#change` element is being added after the DOM loads, so you need to use a delegated event handler. `$(document).on('click', ".ext", function(e) { ...` See the duplicate for more information.

Comment: Thank you Rory McCrossan,
but I don't find de duplicate :/

Comment: It's linked in the yellow box at the top of this page

Comment: :-)
but how can I don't lose the initial DOM?
I dont know delegate event handler for don't refresh all page :/
can you help me?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. All you need to do is change the event handler to what I gave you and your code will work.

Comment: It's work thank you, :-)
I was mistaken in changing the code
:-)